# How can I teleport back to my house or even get close to it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering off to find a wolf, and I got lost. I flew in the air to look for my BIG house and I can't find it. Now, I am totally confused and worried and I don't want to rebuild because it is AWESOME and I used a map, looked it up, and tried everything. So can you please help me? I even tried to teleport but it wouldn't work. I also live by a lake.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, user210995! Sorry, but we can not possibly know where your house is, especially when we have nothing to go off of, like pictures, but even then it is impossible to know what direction it is in. Your best bet would to be to make a map and try to find it on the map.

Answer (score 3):

Did you set a bed?  If so, dying will take you to that bed.

You said you tried using a map.  Did you [zoom out that map](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Zoom_out) fully to zoom step 4?  If not, it's worth a try.  A zoom step 0 map covers 128 X 128 blocks, a zoom step 4 map covers 2048 X 2048 blocks.

If these don't work, my recommendation is [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/).  MCEdit is an external program which can open and search world files.

1. Open MCEdit
2. Select your world in the left menu
3. Click Edit button
4. On the right will be a large graphic output.  At the top of it is 3 buttons labeled 2D, Over, and Cam.  Click the Over button.
5. You will now have a 2 dimensional over view of your world.  Look for evidence of your build.  Move the mouse over this build.  At the bottom of your screen, you will have coordinates.

Here is an image of the program with the Over button and the coordinates circled:
[image: MCEdit]

Click the image to enlarge.  If you look close, my mouse is over what looks like gardens and trails.  Evidence of a build or village and the coordinates are (-260, 0, 320).

Answer (score 1):

Is your house near your world spawn? If it is you can just use a compass to get u closer to your house, this will make searching much easier. If you don’t find your house and have to build a new one, then when you venture out to explore place a block in the general direction of your house every 10 blocks. This block should preferably be a torch or some other block that emits light so you can follow the trail home at night.

Comment: What platform are you playing on?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to use the coordinates displayed on the *F3 Debug Screen* you can just hit **F3 + F2**, that will open the debug screen and screenshot your coordinates.
After that you can just navigate your way back, that's what I always do.
Screenshots are saved in */.minecraft/screenshots.